# nginx ssl with CA

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have a Premium SSL Cert with a provider and they sent me chain.cer, site.pem and site.cer. Do I need to do something special to avoid getting "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" when browsing with the SSL connection?

My config file

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  site.com www.site.com;
        root /home/site/public_html;

        listen       443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate      /root/site.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key  /root/site.key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `cat chain.cer >> site.cer`